# Get JSON from url with file_get_contents

Tags: php, json, file-get-contents

I have a server that provide some data in JSON. 
I tried to get these data with the usual:

```
$res = file_get_contents($url);
$result = json_decode($res);
var_dump($result);
```

But $result is yet a string.
The problem is that the data that comes from file_get_content has some alphanumerical string before data and a zero after.

something like:

```
215ba
{"@attributes":{"ticker":"FCA"},"info...... // here all json data
0
```

I already checked json validity directly from the url and it's properly formatted, I can not understand where zero and 215ba come from.

Obviously I could strip the strings eliminating both but I was wondering if there was a more concrete solution instead of a workaround

PS: unfortunately I can not use cURL

Comment: what is encode type?

Comment: $url is the url of one of our servers that provides dynamic data, but I've already checked the server's output through JSON validator and is correct and properly formatted. The only difference between the result from the browser and the one from file_get_contents are those alphanumeric values at the start and the zero at the end

Comment: Encode type is UTF-8

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Note on the docs for json_decode: http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php

`This function only works with UTF-8 encoded strings.`.

Something like this might fix it:

```
$contents = file_get_contents($url);
$contents = utf8_encode($contents);
$results = json_decode($contents);
```

If that's not working you could use regex to check for new lines. Assuming the json will always be on 1 line.

```
<?php
$contents = file_get_contents($url);
$contents = utf8_encode($contents);
preg_match('/^.+[\n](.+)[\n]./', $contents, $matches);

//the json is in $matches[1]
print_r($matches);
```

Comment: Did it change the output at all?

Comment: @Plastic can share .json file.so we can test it

Comment: It's quite big, where can I paste it?

Comment: I see your edit and i believe at the end i will use this solution, it was my best one since the beginning, i was wandering if there's a way to avoid this "workaround" to a more consistent solution.

Comment: Yeah I'm sure there is a reason for it happening. But this should always work no matter what as long as you put the json on 1 line

Comment: @Plastic If this answers your question can you please put it as the accepted answer?

Comment: @AntonyThompson I'm still trying to find a more consistent solution, otherwise your will be marked as accepted ^^

Comment: PHP.net report (just in the comment) as a solution to simply strip leading BOM (byte order mark) before decoding it with json_decode. I believe this is my best call, thanks for help

Answer (score 1):

could it be that the JSON contains UTF8 characters, so is using a BOM marker at the beginning of the file, and your json_decode function is running in PHP that does not have multi-byte strings enabled?

Comment: It seems the case, do you know an effective way to remove it?

Answer (score -1):

The problem you have been facing I very common, ideally this occurs when json data isn't wellformed such as an unsupported charset included in string or some broken string. Therefore simply try to decode you file contents with UTF-8 support just to be on safer side and less complicating your problem you could either do it with using `utf8_encode()` function in php or using curl to process the utf-8 contents obtained through file.